# Failed to create a seller instance using django signals

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm building a website with 2 user types and still new to django.
And I want to add the functionality to add the seller of the product whenever a product is sold.
I'm sorry that I couldn't explain  it better.
Here's the code of **models.py:**

```
class Ordered(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerProfile, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ordered_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

**product/models.py**

```
class Products(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(SellerProfile, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    product_category = models.CharField(choices = CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length = 100, default = 'eBooks')
    description = models.TextField()
    files = models.FileField(upload_to = 'media/product_files/', null = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 255, unique = True, null = True, blank = True)
```

And this is the signal code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Ordered)
def new_order_for_seller(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    seller = Ordered.seller.sellerprofile
    if created:
        Ordered.objects.create(seller = seller)
```

Any suggestion or correction of the code will be really helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Can yo7u share your `Product` model? I assume it has a FK to the `SellerPorifle`, right?

Comment: Yes, The product model has a foreignkey to the sellerprofile

Comment: Can you add the `Products` model? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Is this change fine? Or do I need to provide more codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `seller` attribute as the `instance.product.seller`:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender = Ordered)
def new_order_for_seller(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.product is not None:
        instance.seller_id = instance.product.seller_id
```

We can do this in a `pre_save` signal to prevent saving the new `Ordered` object a second time.

That being said, since the seller is already determined by the `Product`, it does not make much sense to duplicate this, since it can eventually lead to inconsistencies where the `Seller` of a `Product` changes later, and the `Ordered` is still pointing to the "old" `Seller`.